# Wiremock recording — rewrite responses 'on the fly' when in record mode

Tags: java, mocking, wiremock

I have a wiremock instance running like in the example below:

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.19.0.jar --port=8080 --root-dir="/data" --proxy-all="https://api.github.com" --verbose
```

Now when I start recording for domain `https://api.github.com` at localhost:8080/__admin/recorder/ and request a proxied url like this

https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/contents/

I get a following response:

```
[
  {
    "name": "a-file-in-my-repo.md",
    "path": "content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md",
    "sha": "e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391",
    "size": 0,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/contents/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md?ref=develop",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/blob/develop/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md",
    "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/git/blobs/e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391",
    "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/develop/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md",
    "type": "file",
    "_links": {
      "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/contents/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md?ref=develop",
      "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/git/blobs/e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391",
      "html": "https://github.com/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/blob/develop/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md"
    }
  }
]
```

The "problem" right now is that I want to follow these urls as well e.g. 
`https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/contents/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md?ref=develop` — but then request is executed directly against the github api and not via my configured wiremock proxy.

So I need some rewrite/replace functionality (on wiremock level) that rewrites url's matching https://api.github.com to http://localhost:8080 before persisting the recording so that I get a response like below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "a-file-in-my-repo.md",
    "path": "content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md",
    "sha": "e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391",
    "size": 0,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/contents/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md?ref=develop",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/blob/develop/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md",
    "git_url": "http://localhost:8080/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/git/blobs/e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391",
    "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/develop/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md",
    "type": "file",
    "_links": {
      "self": "http://localhost:8080/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/contents/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md?ref=develop",
      "git": "http://localhost:8080/repos/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/git/blobs/e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391",
      "html": "https://github.com/MyOrganisationName/MyRepoName/blob/develop/content/articles/a-file-in-my-repo.md"
    }
  }
]
```

Is that possible somehow without manual replacement and restarting wiremock each time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To me it sounds like you shouldn't need to rewrite if your client supports an HTTP proxy. WireMock can be setup to act like an [HTTP proxy (Documentation)](http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/#running-as-a-browser-proxy). using the `--enable-browser-proxying` command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

Wiremock will not care about http://localhost:8080 vs http://github.com because it will already be rewriting those if the endpoints match.

If you set it up the way you are intending, you will still have to provide a custom mapping for Wiremock to serve up the correct response.

Can you elaborate on why you would want to replace the urls?

To attempt to answer part of your question, I do not know of a way to transform the response of mappings during the initial proxy, however you can potentially use something like [OpenTable's Wiremock Body Transformer](https://github.com/opentable/wiremock-body-transformer) to sanitize the recordings so they work how you would like in future playback.

Comment: I’m interacting with an api from node.js via wiremock (github api) and while those responds with urls mapping to their api again some response rewrite on wiremock level would be great